# Foundation 5's accordion not working with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, accordion

Foundation 5's accordion works great when I use it as per the documentation and open that page directly. However, if I click to another link on my site and then click to the page with the accordion, then the accordion doesn't expand when I click on the headings :(. I figured maybe it's the turbolinks JavaScript messing with Foundation's accordion. So we added this to the link to the page with the accordion:

```
<li data-no-turbolink><%= link_to 'My accordion page', accordion_page_path %></li>
```

Now it works **better**, but not perfect. If I go to my accordion page from another page, the accordion works. But then when I navigate away and click the back button on my browser, stops working :(.

This must be an extremely common problem as Foundation and Rails are very popular. Any way to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, turbolinks can cause many issues with RoR.

The reason turbolinks breaks your javascript is that document.ready events won't trigger properly. You need to do it on change instead.

**Option 1.** Revise all of the Javascript (Not easy or recommend)

```
var on_load = function() { 
}
$(document).ready(on_load)
$(window).bind('page:change', on_load)
```

**Option 2.** Use the Jquery-Turbolinks gem.

The jquery turbolinks gem is designed to get around this problem. However, you need to read the docs, and make sure to install it properly. (It's a tricky beast.)

**Option 3.** Remove Turbolinks

If it's causing you to much trouble, you can just remove it. Delete it from the gemfile, remove `turbolinks-tracked: true` from your assets in the application layout, and wave turbolinks goodbye. I will admit, I have done this several of times. :\