# Rails 4 Foundation Top-Bar Menu not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I am using Rails 4.1.7, Foundation 5.5 and tried Foundation 5.4.3.2

I went to the Foundation Page and tried the example for the top-bar navigation

Can be found [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html) and is the exact code used in _header.html.erb.

Everything is working, except for the menu item that shows up when decreasing the size of the browser (tried on chrome and firefox). When I click the item nothing happens.

My understanding was that the example code should reproduce a navigation bar where menu is clickable and shows the dropdown with having to add any code?

I created a new rails app just to test this out.

_header.html.erb partial:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
      <h1><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>
    </li>
     <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
  </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Right Button Active</a></li>
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="#">Right Button Dropdown</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Active link in dropdown</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Left Nav Section -->
    <ul class="left">
      <li><a href="#">Left Nav Button</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.7'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
#gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'sass-rails', github: 'rails/sass-rails', branch: 'master'
gem 'sass', '~> 3.3.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
gem 'foundation-rails', '~> 5.4.3.1'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development
```

application.html.erb file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "foundation-rails" %></title>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>

  <body data-no-turbolink>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="small-8 columns"><%= yield %></div>
    <div class="small-4 columns"><p>Test</p></div>
  </div>
  </body>  
</html>
```

I tried looking for the answer online but did not find anything recent discussion and all the solutions I found did not work for me (disabling turbolinks, changing the way the foundation library is called..)

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Jean

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue with the turbolinks gem and found this solution for rails 4.2.0 and foundation 5.5.1.

In your gemfile:
    
    `gem 'jquery-turbolinks'`

On the command line:
    
    `bundle install`

then in your application.js:
    
    `//= require jquery
    //= require jquery.turbolinks
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require foundation
    //= require_tree .
    $(function(){ $(document).foundation()});
    //= require turbolinks`
 
Restart server.

This fixed all the issues with the foundation javascripts not loading by making sure turbolinks runs last using the jquery-turbolinks gem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following in your js?

```
//= require foundation
$(document).foundation();
```

In fact, the foundation gem you are using has a generator you can/should run:

```
rails g foundation:install
```

Comment: yes I did that / have that in my file , as I said every other property of the bar is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This really sounds like a javacript/turbolinks issue.

I've explained how to disable turbo-links already, so I linked to an earlier response.

Create a branch and see if the following solves the problem. If it does, turbo-links is the issue.

[Previous Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133148/foundation-5s-accordion-not-working-with-rails-4/26133354#26133354)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is more widespread than just the top bar JavaScript, in fact, it involved all of Foundation's JavaScript on my machine. After trying many solutions without much success, I finally just started removing code that looked troublesome.

After running `rails g foundation:install` and allowing the command to overwrite the main application ERB file.

In your application.html.erb, change this...

`<%= javascript_include_tag "application" 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

to this...

`<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`

This single line of code fixed my foundation-rails gem JS, I hope this helps anyone who comes here in the future.